# How to Mint a Fungible Token with Metadata on Solana using @Solana/web3.js

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

I am fairly new to Solana development and currently learning how to mint fungible tokens with custom metadata. I am able to mint a SPL-Token on devnet using spl-token library, however finding it bit confusing for minting a token with metadata. which library is preferred for creating metadata, is it @metaplex/foundation.js or @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata? I also found some people are using @metaboss.
Wanted to know which is the preferred approach to mint new token with metadata. I would like to add this Token on Radium with openmarket ID, does it need a specific way in which metadata will be added.

Thanks
Sam